# Jsoup doesnt show certain element which is visible at webpage

Tags: web-scraping, jsoup

we can see at this page https://www.futbin.com/21/player/541/lionel-messi,
there is ps-lowest-1 span element and when I took this element via

`doc.getElementById("ps-lowest-1")` it doesn't give me data-price attr also text is coming dash, what may cause this issue.

Answer (score 1):

What you needed to do was look through the network http request/responses in Chromes Dev tools.

If you find the value you're looking for (`688000` for Ps4), you can look through the request/responses and you'll eventually find the value in a request to:

https://www.futbin.com/21/playerPrices?player=158023&rids=50489671&_=1603238284786

This is the data I think you want.

In order to parse it you can look at using:

```java
String url = "https://www.futbin.com/21/playerPrices?player=158023&rids=50489671&_=1603238284786";
ResponseEntity<String> document = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
String json = document.getBody();
List<String> listOfItems = JsonPath.read(json, "$.path[*].to.items.you.want");
```

This should give you a rough idea how to get the data you want.

Comment: pretty good...  **Chrome Developer Tools** usually looks like one giant haystack (trying to find a needle).